# WCF net tcp port sharing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

I have 2 WCF services each hosted in its own console app.

they are hosted at:

```
net.tcp://computername:7777/Service1
net.tcp://computername:7777/Service2
```

each has its own contract.
i want them to use the same port, so i read a lot on the subject, and did the following:

1. Enabled the net tcp port sharing service.
2. Registered the url`s using the commands:

`netsh http add urlacl user=domain\username url=net.tcp://+:7777/Service1`

`netsh http add urlacl user=domain\username url=net.tcp://+:7777/Service2`

1. enabled the `PortSharingEnabled=true` on the bindings in for each WCF service
2. hosted each one in it`s own console app.

if i start both console apps, the second one always gives this exception on the call to the host's `Open()` method:

```
    AddressAlreadyInUseException. The transport manager failed to listen on the supplied 
    URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: the URI is already registered with the 
    service.
```

when i host them both in the same console app, it all works just fine.

**my question is:** how to get it working when each service is hosted in it's own console app.

Comment: I got this to work replicating all of your steps except "Registered the url's using the commands:" in Windows 7, .NET 4.5.

Comment: it seems you did everything necessary for port sharing. just double-check the following: 1 you created binding with portsharingEnabled = true, did you set the bindingConfiguration value in tag endPoint (in configuration file)? 2 try your program with another port number just in case settings in your previous test program did something prevent port-sharing happening.  3 from what i know, the netsh command is not required for port-sharing.

Comment: @Jon_Lindeheim thanks, at least i know its supposed to work. all i need to do is recreate everything from scratch, and hope the mistake i did make will sorface. i`ll try to post back ASAP

Comment: @yyou thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  Jon_Lindeheim and you stated, this should work fine. so i recreated everything from scratch as follows:

I have two WCF services that had the same **base address** and a different **relative URI**

i.e. 
for service 1:

```
    <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://computername:7777/" />
    ...
    <endpoint address = "/service1" ... />
```

and for service 2:

```
    <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://computername:7777/" />
    ...
    <endpoint address = "/service2" ... />
```

I was not aware that base addresses must be different not just the eventual absolute URI.

so the following works fine:
for service 1:

```
    <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://computername:7777/service1/" />
    ...
    <endpoint address = "/service1" ... />
```

for service 2:

```
    <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://computername:7777/service2/" />
    ...
    <endpoint address = "/service2" ... />
```

(why the first erroneous way still works when all is in one process, i think it's related to the way port sharing routes the traffic on a process based way).

Thanks again