# netsh http add urlacl fail - parameter is incorrect

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2008, netsh

I'm trying to register wcf net tcp port sharing, for a process to listen on this port (currently the client machine can't even ping this port eventhough the process is up so I read this command is needed):

```
netsh http add urlacl user=domain\svcUser url=net.tcp://+:8092/Service1
```

getting `Url reservation failed, Error 87. The parameter is incorrect`.

Also tried changing the user, the port, removing the `Service1`, adding a trailing `/`. Is there anything else that should be done?

Remark: The following command does succeed (but does not help): `netsh http add urlacl user=domain\svcUser url=http://+:8092/Service1`

[This post shows the usage of netsh in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653534/wcf-net-tcp-port-sharing)

[This post deals with error 87 but did not solve in my case](https://serverfault.com/questions/283237/netsh-exe-error-87)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the command succeed but it didn't work. This is not normal.

Maybe you can try this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8092 user=domain\svcUser
```

Comment: As mentioned in question also removed the Service1 (failed) and tried with http: (didnt help)

Comment: Maybe you could try [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035131/how-to-resolve-url-reservation-add-failed-error-87) to see if they work.